# Problems preparing a disk image for upload to Azure

Tags: azure

I am trying to upload a disk image for use on the Azure cloud platform. I've been following through [these instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-redhat-create-upload-vhd/), but image resizing is giving me a hard time.

I start out with a qcow2 image:

```
$ qemu-img info --output=json myimage.qcow2 
{
    "virtual-size": 8589934592,
    "filename": "myimage.qcow2",
    "cluster-size": 65536,
    "format": "qcow2",
    "actual-size": 1468272640,
    "format-specific": {
        "type": "qcow2",
        "data": {
            "compat": "0.10",
            "refcount-bits": 16
        }
    },
    "dirty-flag": false
}
```

I convert this image into a raw disk:

```
$ qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O raw myimage.qcow2 myimage.img
```

Then, following along with the instructions, I round the size of to an
even number of megabytes:

```
$ MB=$((1024 * 1024))
$ size=$(qemu-img info -f raw --output json "$1" |
  gawk 'match($0, /"virtual-size": ([0-9]+),/, val) {print val[1]}')
$ rounded_size=$((($size/$MB + 1) * $MB))
$ echo $rounded_size
8590983168
```

And resize the image:

```
$ qemu-img resize -f raw myimage.img $rounded_size
```

Which gets me:

```
$ qemu-img info -f raw --output=json myimage.img 
{
    "virtual-size": 8590983168,
    "filename": "myimage.img",
    "format": "raw",
    "actual-size": 1458573312,
    "dirty-flag": false
}
```

(That's exactly 8193 MB).

When I convert this to VHD format:

```
$ qemu-img convert -f raw -o subformat=fixed -O vpc myimage.img myimage.vhd
```

I end up with a file that is no longer the correct size:

```
$ ls -l myimage.vhd 
-rw-r--r--. 1 lars lars 8591450624 Apr 14 12:04 myimage.vhd
```

And when I try to upload this, Azure yells at me:

```
$ azure vm image create myimage myimage.vhd  --os Linux --location 'East US'
info:    Executing command vm image create
+ Retrieving storage accounts                                                  
info:    VHD size : 8193 MB
info:    Uploading 8390088.5 KB
...
info:    https://....blob.core.windows.net/vm-images/myimage.vhd was uploaded successfully
error:   The VHD https://....blob.core.windows.net/vm-images/myimage.vhd has an unsupported virtual size of 8591450112 bytes.  The size must be a whole number (in MBs).
info:    Error information has been recorded to /home/lars/.azure/azure.err
error:   vm image create command failed
```

How do I appease the Azure monster and make it stop yelling at me?

(FYI: I am using: `qemu-img version 2.5.0 (qemu-2.5.0-10.fc23)`)

Answer (score 8):

It looks like this is due to an incompatibility between `qemu-img` and Microsoft Azure (I hesitate to call it a "bug" because it appears that there are multiple "standards" covering vpc format images).

The problem is that `qemu-img` will, by default, create an image aligned to the nearest CHS geometry, while Azure wants images aligned to the nearest whole MB.

There is already a fix for this in the QEMU repository; the commit that fixes it is [fb9245c](http://repo.or.cz/qemu/kevin.git/commit/fb9245c2610932d33ce148b58714fcc7b3c6eb5f), the commit message for which is:

> block/vpc: give option to force the current_size field in
>   .bdrv_create
>
> When QEMU creates a VHD image, it goes by the original spec,
>   calculating the current_size based on the nearest CHS geometry (with
>   an exception for disks > 127GB).
>
> Apparently, Azure will only allow images that are sized to the nearest
>   MB, and the current_size as calculated from CHS cannot guarantee that.
>
> Allow QEMU to create images similar to how Hyper-V creates images, by
>   setting current_size to the specified virtual disk size.  This
>   introduces an option, force_size, to be passed to the vpc format
>   during image creation, e.g.:
>
> ```
> qemu-img convert -f raw -o force_size -O vpc test.img test.vhd
> ```
>
> When using the "force_size" option, the creator app field used by QEMU
>   will be "qem2" instead of "qemu", to indicate the difference. In light
>   of this, we also add parsing of the "qem2" field during vpc_open.

I can confirm that with this change applied locally, I can run...

```
qemu-img convert -f raw -O vpc -o subformat=fixed,force_size myimage.raw myimage.vhd
```

...and generate a disk image that will successfully upload to Azure.